# im getting this error refrence error in node.js. Can someone explain the source of this serror

Tags: node.js

{url: `${api}/products` , methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS']},
ReferenceError: api is not defined at authJwt (C:\Users\abuba\Desktop\BACKEND\helpers\jwt.js:9:22)
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');

```
function authJwt(){
    const secret = process.env.secret;
    return expressJwt({
        secret,
        algorithms: ['HS256']
    }).unless({
        path: [
            {url: `${api}/products` , methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS']},
            `${api}/users/login`,
            `${api}/users/register`

        ]
    })
}


module.exports = authJwt;
```

Comment: Everything is in the error message. The variable / constant `api` is not defined, you need to define it to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define some parameter named `api`.
Like

```
const api = 'my-endpoint/sample'
```

Whenever using template string, you have to define parameter when using like this
`${}`, can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) about template strings.

So, like this you can use it:

```
const api = 'my-endpoint/sample'
url: `${api}/products`
```

this will return url as:

```
url = 'my-endpoint/sample/products'
```

Comment: sure, if this answer your question you can accept this as answer or upvote :'). Happy to help you mate, cheers. @Abubakarkhalid